# Mailaparse on XAMPP 1.7.3

Tags: php, macos, xampp, pecl

I'm needing mailparse installed on my xampp.
I've done `pecl install mailparse` but I get an error that mbstring is not installed, but it is.. Or at least that is what phpinfo() says.

So I'm doing `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles: sudo ./bin/pecl install --nodeps mailparse`

BUT.. when the make starts it fails with a big load of errors... How can I install mailparse on a xampp installation? Or maybe I could compile it? but not sure how, not in osx...

Any ideas?

[Here you can see the complete trace](http://pastebin.ca/2046446) done with `sudo ./bin/pecl install --nodeps mailparse > dump`

---

FIXED! if someone is interested on the solution, you must have installed [devel-package](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-macosx-1.7.3-dev.dmg) of XAMPP, and run the pecl script having in mind that must be comipled for i386 arch.

```
sudo su -

export CFLAGS="-arch i386"

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install --nodeps mailparse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear install pecl/mailparse
```

From: http://wiki.cerb4.com/wiki/Installing_PHP_Mailparse#Mac_OS_X_.28XAMPP.29

Comment: Nope, sorry. That doesn't work.. It's almost the same as doing pecl install mailparse and drops the same dump I've posted

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pear install pecl/mailparse-2.1.6
```

Try this is if you have installed Php 5.X

If you got error like

> Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
>   $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

and then retry.

```
brew install autoconf
```

and run the command