# How to install APC XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, apc

I tried to find in Google how to install "APC" and didn't found way.
Someone know how to?

- by the way, I have mac

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install apc
```

or you cold follow these instructions [here](http://elinkmedia.net.au/2010/05/03/compile-apc-for-xampp-on-snow-leopard/).

but for booth you will need the developer tools.

Comment: Thanks! now how I enable him?

Answer (score 1):

This worked (at last) for me on OSX Lion:

## 1.

Download and install the XAMPP Developer package from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html#849

## 2.

Make sure you have Xcode installed

## 3.

... and autoconf

> sudo port install autoconf

## 4.

Open a new terminal and run:

> sudo su -
>
> export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/:/opt/local/bin/:$PATH
>
> xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
>
> CFLAGS="-arch i386" /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install apc

## 5.

Restart Apache

## Sources

Instructions adapted from several sources, including:

- http://blog.laaz.org/tech/2010/08/27/xdebug-with-xampp-on-mac-os-x/
- [Mailaparse on XAMPP 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666245/mailaparse-on-xampp-1-7-3)

Comment: error when installing. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:61:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed